# Непонятные отступы на странице

Tags: html, css

Между логотипом и  появился непонятный отступ.

Откуда он берется и как его убрать?

[[image: на картинке отступы указаны красным]

**HTML:**

```
<header>
<img src="http://pfo.spr.ru/pages_logotip/4444176/15009.png" />

    <div class="contact-info-top">
      <div class="contact-info-top-logo">
      </div>
      <p>По всем вопросам</p>
      <span>8 800 555-35-35</span>
      <p>Пн - Пт / 10:00-19:00</p>
    </div>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="###">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Мужские часы</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">Женские часы</a></li>
        <li><a href="###">О нас</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

**CSS**

```
/*-----COMMON-----*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic,cyrillic-ext);

body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}

/*-----HEADER STYLE-----*/
header {
  position: relative;
}

.contact-info-top {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 2em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

.contact-info-top-logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: -55px;
  top: 15%;
}

.contact-info-top p {
  margin: 0 auto;   
  color: #2A282D;
}

.contact-info-top span {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  font: 1.2em Lobster;
}

header nav {
  background: black;
  height: 3em;
}

header nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.6em;
}

header nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

header nav a:hover {
  color: #7EC91B;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ns2puuy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это `ul` дает отступ

```
ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

добавьте -

```
header nav ul{
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rn5zopvz/

Используйте cssreset - http://cssreset.com

Comment: Спасибо, почему-то в инспекторе фаерфокса ul отображается без отступов

Answer (score 1):

```
ul {
margin-top: 0;
}
```

По умолчанию у списков есть свой `margin`.

Comment: Спасибо, про это я догадывался, но хотелось бы узнать почему вообще возник этот отступ? Можете в сторону теории меня подтолкнуть?

Comment: Изменил ответ в другую сторону и описал почему так.